# TypeScript convert tuple type with nullable type to tuple with non-nullable type

Tags: typescript, tuples, type-inference, metatype

I am going to function to memoize return values from the function given.

```js
const memoize = (value, onHandle) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < value.length; index++) {
    if (value[index] === null || value[index] === undefined) {
      return
    }
  }
  //
  // Check if there is memoized value with same parameters.
  //
  return onHandle(value)
}
```

The callback function `onHandle` receives non nullable values and return a value with being memoized to cache object.
I should declare types that convert tuples with nullable type to tuples with non nullable like this below.

```
type Tuple = [number | undefined, string, boolean, string | undefined]
type StrictTuple = [number, string, boolean, string]
```

I have tried several times, but inferring tuple with non nullable is so challenging actually. Are there any ways to draw tuple type with non nullable value only?

Here are the failed code.

```
type StrictTuple<T extends [unknown, ...unknown[]]> = T extends [
  unknown,
  ...unknown[]
]
  ? T[number] extends null | undefined
    ? never
    : T[number] extends infer U
    ? U extends null | undefined
      ? never
      : T
    : never
  : never;
type Example1 = StrictTuple<[1 | undefined, 2, "3", true | null, boolean]> 
// Example1 shows [1 | undefined, 2, "3", true | null, boolean]
```

```
type StrictTuple<T extends [E, ...E[]], E = unknown> = T[number] extends infer U ? U extends null | undefined ? never : [U, ...U[]]: never
type Example2 = StrictTuple<[1, 2, "3", boolean, number | undefined]>
// Example2 shows [number, ...number[]] | [false, ...false[]] | [true, ...true[]] | ["3", ..."3"[]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to do this:

```
type Strictify<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] & {} }
```

TypeScript automatically [produces tuple/array types when mapping over generic tuple/array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays). The definition uses [the `-?` mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to say that any [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) should be made required.  Each property value type is [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with the empty object type `{}` to remove `null` and `undefined` from the domain.  I also could have used [the `NonNullable<>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) [which is (now) implemented as such an intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing).

Let's test it:

```
type Example1 = Strictify<[number | undefined, string, boolean, string | undefined];
//   ^? type Example1 = [number, string, boolean, string]

type Example2 = Strictify<[1, 2, "3", boolean, number | undefined]>;
//   ^? type Example2 = [1, 2, "3", boolean, number]

type Example3 = Strictify<[string | null, number | undefined, boolean?]>;
//   ^? type Example3 = [string, number, boolean]
```

Looks good.  Note that I didn't call this `StrictTuple` because it also works on non-arraylike objects:

```
type ExampleObj = Strictify<{ a: string, b?: number, c: boolean | null, d: Date };
/*   ^? type ExampleObj = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
    d: Date;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/FAFwngDgpgBAyiATgSwMYmQMzAHgCoB8MAvDAN4wDaA0jMgHYwDWUYA9pjHgLoC0A-AC4uNbjABk5AL4wpwUJFgBRAB4BDALYQANlACMJeEjQZsOSvQCuGgEZREMAD4xL9ACZRMDKG4A0MAGdjegBzfxs2Nl01en8glFCnF3dPbzduAG5gAHpsmHyAPX4YcGgYVU0dfUMLaztEOOCwmAioqBjGhJDueVLldS1dACZDBBR0LFxKPX8h-wAiAGZ58Mjo2JgrW3sk1w8veh9uAizc-JgiksVygaqR0mnZheXVto7NuvsehTKKwahFqNjBMzJR4gwQkkrNptP4tvVdikDj5Xut+MdTnlCsU+jdKrpAQ9waE4Z8Gi01u16N9cX8qgB5GwAKyB41MuAoamExOaNiEH225NQwla6yhlhh-jcwgAImoQLApKcAFTnS60266Rks0hkYDnGBcwJNLIGmzCeH2U3nYUUt70a35aUwOUKrIyZXZYBAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this utility to allow part of the tuple (only the first half) to be non-nullable, while the second half remains typed with a chance of nullable.

```
export type MakeNonNullableUpTo<T extends unknown[], N extends number, O extends unknown[] = []> =
  O['length'] extends N
      ? [...{ [K in keyof O]: NonNullable<O[K]> }, ...T]
      : T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
          ? MakeNonNullableUpTo<Rest, N, [...O, NonNullable<First>]>
          : O;

// e.g.
type MyArray = [string | null, number | undefined, boolean | null, string?, number?];
type FirstThreeNonNullable = MakeNonNullableUpTo<MyArray, 3>; // [string, number, boolean, string?, number?]
```